# Gitlab CI auto-tagging after merge

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gitlab

I want to add a stage in the gitlab ci that auto tags the latest merge as "latest", deleting/overwriting the tag if it already exists.. but I'm kind of stuck

I tried to just write it in the `gitlab-ci.yml` file but got a permission error so I moved it to a script file but I'm not sure how to implement the stage..

`tag.sh`:

```sh
SCRIPT_DIR=$(cd $(dirname $0); pwd)
GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT=no

# include common utilities
test -f $SCRIPT_DIR/functions && . $SCRIPT_DIR/functions

# 1. setup git
git_init $CI_PROJECT_PATH $GITLAB_USER_EMAIL

# 2. tag as "latest"
(git tag -d latest && git push origin --delete latest) || git tag latest
git push origin --tags
```

`(git_init function)`:

```sh
git_init () {
  local project_path=$1
  local user_email=$2

  git remote set-url --push origin ssh://git@<cdn>/$project_path.git
  git config user.email "$user_email"
  git remote -v
}
```

`gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yml
stages:
  - lint
  - sa
  - test
  - tag
  - build
  - deploy
  - release
...
tag:
  stage: tag
  script:
    - scripts/tag.sh
```

The pipeline succeeds but I don't see a new tag.. and it's also running when the merge request is testing. Is there a way to set a stage to only run after the MR is merged?

I've seen the docs for `when: merge_request` but that doesn't seem to solve only on merged MR's..

> The functions I've mostly copied from our team's other projects and the inner workings of the ci is somewhat confusing to me.